# Excel Application open new workbook after running script ended

Tags: excel, vba

I have private sub for ThisWorkbooks to run a code to send email upon opening the file. After settle everything I will close working workbooks. I am sharing this code with other colleague. Usually, for me my Excel application only left with grey screen (like picture attach) but now its open new workbook Book1.xlsx if my colleague run this code from his computer.. And if didn't close Book1.xlsx  the script cannot be run again. Why this happening? I don't want to use `Application.Quit` because still got another working excel that I don't wish to close at that time.

below is my code:

Grey Excel Application

[image]

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Call Send_Email

    Workbooks("Automail_V4.xlsm").Close

    End Sub

   



    Sub Send_Email()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("DL")

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Dim fname As String
    fname = "filepath(MasterFile)"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=fname, ReadOnly:=True

    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    outMail.Display

    With outMail
                .Subject = "Email[Daily]"
                .To = "receipent"
                .HTMLBody = "Hi & paste info get from MasterFile.xlsx"
         End With
         
    outMail.Send

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"))

    Set outMail = Nothing
    Set outApp = Nothing

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Workbooks("MasterFile.xlsx").Close savechanges:=False

    With Application
       .EnableEvents = True
      .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you both using the same version of Excel? If not, who is using which version?

Comment: @braX, mine 2019 and friend 2016 ..  is it the default setting?

Comment: I think it would be better to address why the script cannot be run again. There's no reason it cannot be fixed if you can identify why running it under both conditions is problematic. Excel did change the default setting for number of sheets in a new workbook from 3 to 1 around that time, but you can make it whatever you want under the excel settings, if that helps.